find the 3 digits that calculate the same
Suzie was busy working in her office and helping compile Clayton’s expenses for which he has a daily elevenses allowance of less than £10 when she noticed that the three digits making up the amount of money he had spent on his elevenses and the balance of the amount unclaimed was a rearrangement of the same three digits! And furthermore, the actual full allowable amount was also an arrangement of those same three digits. How much is Clayton’s daily elevense’s allowance?

His allowance is 0.00 :P

Is this because there is no 3 digits that can be re-arranged? or is this a quess? thanks

Is the currency important?


 Just for fun, I'm assuming this took place pre-decimilization.  His allowance was £5/6/– (five pounds and six shillings).  He spent £5/0/6 (five pounds and sixpence), leaving 5/6 (five shillings and sixpence).


 (After decimilization, £5.04, £4.50, and 54p, or £4.50, £4.05, and 45p, work. A tip of my hat to Daniel Mathias for pointing out that £9.54, £4.95, and £4.59 do, too.)


It is merely the sum of the two decimal solutions you presented. It would be better as an addition to your answer rather than as a separate answer.
